# Weird amp behaviour

Tags: amplifiers, electronics

My solid-state amp isn't putting out any sounds lately. But when I turn it off there is a short time where I can hear my guitar playing until the amp turns completely off. What can cause this strange behavior?

Comment: Sounds a bit like a worn capacitor somewhere… Unfortunately without more information on the complete setup it is hard to give an accurate answer…

Comment: @Tom What more Information would you need? I should be able to provide all the Infos :D

Comment: It could also be a failing component going into thermal shutdown.  I'd suggest taking it in for service.

Comment: I would tend to agree with @Duston if you are not too much into electronic. Have you tried the guitar on another amp? Is the sound completely off or very very low? Does it happen gradually?

Comment: There is no sound, just noise till I turn it off, I'm fairly competent with electronics soldering, programming .. . I also have capacitors on mass at home but I'm a noob when it comes to troubleshooting old analog circuits. 
On the other hand could I replace the amp and just keep the 50w 4Ohm Speaker, got any amps in mind for that job ?

Comment: Sounds like a capacitor needs to be replaced. The capacitors in power amps pack a hefty punch. If you're not confident in how to safely discharge a capacitor, don't touch it. What make/model is the amp? The value (actual, or emotional) will determine whether it's worth paying an engineer to replace the capacitors.

Comment: Sometimes troubleshooting dead capacitors is easy: if they have leaked or have another color remove it and test it with a multimeter ;). But to add on @PeteCon be **extremely** careful, these things bite!!

Comment: I'd like to know what the amp is - some old SS amps should be dropped unceremoniously in the skip, whilst others are absolutely always worth repairing. BTW, if you're having caps replaced, get them all replaced, not just the duff ones. The BBC used to replace all caps in all equipment on a 5-year diary. After having replaced the valves in an old Vibralux with no sonic benefit, after a quick chat with the BBC brown-coats we also replaced the power caps - pure joy. It looks a bit odd replacing huge chewed toffees with weeny blue cylinders, wires stretched as far as they can, but by heck it works

Comment: If it has a headphone out that cuts the main speaker when engaged, see if the headphones still emit sound: it could just be the mechanical cutoff.

Answer (score 2):

In order to diagnose the problem with this amp you'll need to trace a signal through the circuitry of the amplifier to find the defective component. If I had it on my workbench, the first thing I would look for would be defective field  effect transistors (FET), I've seen a few amps act this way and replacing the FETs fixed the problem. If the problem isn't with the FETs, then I'd check for a defective zener diode, this can also cause an amp to act in this manner. Both parts are inexpensive and easy to replace, so it shouldn't break the bank to fix it.